# Email validation in createuser wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using createuser wizard for creating new users. I'm not using any membership provider. While creating a new user, the user has to enter the email address in the createuser wizard. How to know that the entered email address is correct? If a user enters the email as abcd@abcd.com, how to know that it is a valid email address?

The email regular expression given in MSDN website does not work for me. It is `<asp:createuserwizard id="Createuserwizard1" runat="server" emailregularexpression='@"^([\w-\.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$"' emailregularexpressionerrormessage="E-mail address must be in a valid format"> </asp:createuserwizard>`

Comment: This question is asked all the time.  Try a search and you should be able to find one!

Comment: Valid email as in correctly formed or as in actually exists?

Comment: Because it's a really common question that you could've found the answer by googling it. I won't downvote it, but you should be more careful and put a little more effort next time.

Comment: Do you want to validate it is a correct syntax for an e-mail, or if it is a valid e-mail account that the user must confirm by sending them an actual e-mail with a validation code?

Comment: If you need a e-mail syntax regular expression, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/2291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:createuserwizard id="Createuserwizard1" runat="server" emailregularexpression="^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$" emailregularexpressionerrormessage="E-mail address must be in a valid format"> </asp:createuserwizard>
```

This expression for email in createuser wizard helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Send a message to the email address to which the user has to respond.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is at first to check with a regex (to ensure it contains a `@` and a domain) and then to send a confirmation mail to that address. Only when the new user clicks on a link in that confirmation e-mail, his account is established and you can be asured that the e-mail address is correct.